# Store expanded entity in NoSql

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

In the book of adrian hall, there is a sample which fetches objects with sub objects.
In this case it looks like this:

```
public class JobDTO : EntityData
{
    public string AgentId { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? EndTime { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }  

    public virtual CustomerDTO Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual List<EquipmentDTO> Equipments { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, there is one customer as complex data and multiple equipments.

On the client side, can we store complex data like this in the nosql offline store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On the client side, can we store complex data like this in the nosql offline store?

According to your description, I have checked [The Domain Manager](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/domainmgr/) from adrian hall's book. Also, I have tested the similar code, and the complex data could be stored in the SQLite offline store as follows:

[image]

For offline Sync, when pushing local Job table to the remote, the relationships `Customer` and `Equipments` need to be ignored by the server-side as follows:

```html
// For incoming requests, ignore the relationships
cfg.CreateMap<JobDTO, Job>()                                            
    .ForMember(job => job.Customer, map => map.Ignore())
    .ForMember(job => job.Equipments, map => map.Ignore());
```

As [Existing Table Relationships with the MappedEntityDomainManager](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/domainmgr/#existing-table-relationships-with-the-mappedentitydomainmanager) states for syncing the Job table:

> Customer and Equipment data all comes down as one record. This has a side effect of ensuring that **the Customer and Equipment data is read-only**. You can **only update the information in the Job table**.

Also, as Adrian Hall mentioned that he prefers handling tables individually and handling relationship management on the mobile client manually. This causes more code on the mobile client but makes the server much simpler by avoiding most of the complexity of relationships.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, why not.
Just follow this document to using off-line store
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-offline-data